# Include one Dockerfile within another

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two Dockerfiles. They are built in my CI using `docker build`, and they build fine.

First, `baseimage/Dockerfile`, which is built and tagged as `baseimage:1`:

```
ARG AMAZONLINUX_VERSION="2023"
# Use Amazon Linux 2023 as the base image
FROM amazonlinux:${AMAZONLINUX_VERSION} as builder

# ... guts omitted for brevity...
```

Second, `devcontainer/Dockerfile`, which is built and tagged as `devcontainer:1`:

```
# Use your custom base image
FROM registry.gitlab.com/.../baseimage:1

# ... guts omitted for brevity
```

Each builds fine on their own, and they are being built in my CI/CD and pushed to my container repo on GitLab. So far, all is well.

The problem is I want to shorten the CI build time. `baseimage` has to be built before `devcontainer` can be built. And, yes - I do need both images; they serve different purposes. The build process is currently taking about 12 minutes and I want to get that down as much as possible.

These two Dockerfiles will always be built at the same time, and `devcontainer` will always use the latest `baseimage` as the base. So I thought I could speed up the CI by building them both at the same time, instead of doing one then the other.

This would be easy if there were such a thing as an `INCLUDE` statement ina  Dockerfile. Like this:

Proposed fantasy `devcontainer/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM INCLUDE ../baseimage/Dockerfile

# ... same guts as before
```

I think this would work perfect, but there is no such thing.

How can this be done? Should this be done?

Note: This question is not a dupe of [Can a Dockerfile extend another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362233/can-a-dockerfile-extend-another-one). The highest-voted answer there proposes using a multi stage build to produce a single image. I need two images, one base off the other. There is one answer that proposes using someone's custom tool, but I can't introduce a dependency like that in to my CI. I need either something idiomatic and supported, or custom built by me.

Comment: Why do you expect this would reduce build time?  It sounds like you'd be running the exact same build steps, the exact same number of times, but in a single `docker build` invocation instead of two.

Comment: @DavidMaze my thinking was it would be faster to run both docker builds in a single GitLab CI job instead of in two sequential GitLab CI jobs. I figured the time savings would come from 1) only spinning up one job instead of two, 2) potentially being able to benefit from the docker cache.